# Adding span in navigation

Tags: drupal, navigation, drupal-7, html, drupal-theming

I am Developing a website in Drupal 7

http://lorrells.seoperspective.com/

Now Problem here is the sidebar menu (on Left)
my client wants something like in image below
[image]

means he wants a small amount of text below the link
so I was thinking to add "title" text below in span where I can style it

What I want is

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-359 first"><a class="Litigation" title="Our niche Litigation Department punches well above its weight." href="http://lorrells.seoperspective.com/Litigation">Litigation</a><span>Our niche Litigation Department punches well above its weight.</span></li>
</ul>
```

code in page.tpl.php

```
 <div class="sidebar_menu"> 
     <?php

        $menu = menu_navigation_links('menu-sidebarmenu');
        print theme('links__menu-sidebarmenu', array('links' => $menu));


    ?>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1:
Have you had a look at [this](http://drupal.org/project/menu_html) contrib module? It will expose you a checkbox to enter html in menu titles. But am warning you, html in menu items are risky business. Make sure the permissions are set correctly.

Method 2:
Another way you could achieve the same effect could be creating a block with custom markup. But then if you give permission to edit that to your client, that would probably be a disaster waiting to happen.

Method 3:
If you are comfortable in playing with hooks, [hook_menu_link_alter(&$item)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/7) could be used to set html attribute to true, and also reformat the title, the way you want it.

Answer (score 3):

```
function ThemeName_link($variables) {
  return '<a href="' . check_plain(url($variables['path'], $variables['options'])) . '"' . drupal_attributes($variables['options']['attributes']) . '><span>' . ($variables['options']['html'] ? $variables['text'] : check_plain($variables['text'])) . '</span></a>';
}
```

it's for all links in your theme.